# Accessing a JSON array from AJAX return, why am I not getting any return value?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON array like this:

```
{"items":[{"itemId":"1","ndc":"ndc 1","upc":"upc 1","description":"Test Item 1","abc6":"11"}],"searchString":"1","lineNumber":10}
```

I'm using jQuery AJAX like this:

```
function ajaxGetData() {
        var productid = $(this).val();
        var line = parseInt($(this).parents("td").siblings(".row-target").text());
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "searchItem.do?originalInput=" + productid + "&lineNumber=" + line,
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                var done = data.items["description"];
                alert(done);
            });
    }
```

My alert is coming up undefined. How do I access the data in this object?

Comment: try parsing `data` into a javascript object or add `dataType:json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`items` is an array.  You have to access the first array element.

```
data.items[0].description
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
data.items[0]['description']
```

You've got an object containing an array of objects, but are refering to an object-of-object only.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do:

```
var descriptions=[];
$.each(data.items, function(idx,item){
    descriptions.push(item.description);
});

alert(descriptions);
```

If I need description and an itemId in this array, it would be:

```
var descriptions=[];
$.each(data.items, function(idx,item){
    descriptions.push({
        itemId     : item.itemId,
        description: item.description
    );
});

alert(descriptions);
```

The key is that `items` is a collection that has no property called `description`. You have to enumerate through each item to access it.

One more thing, if you are using `item["description"]` instead of `item.description`, you will lose the intellisense in your code editor.